# Objective C not finding file in resources folder

Tags: objective-c, resourcebundle, nsbundle

I'm trying to access a file in my resources folder as follows:

```
NSLog(@"%@",defaultPlistName);
NSString *pListPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:defaultPlistName ofType:@"plist"];
NSLog(@"pListPath: %@ ",pListPath);
```

This is the output:

```
2015-03-13 10:08:43.078 MyApp[628:214709] DefaultConfig
2015-03-13 10:09:26.560 MyApp[628:214709] pListPath: (null)
```

A file named "DefaultConfig.plist" exists in the resource folder.

Why isn't this file being found?

Comment: This might be silly question, but has the file been added to the target properly? Check Copy Bundle resources in the build settings.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I had just posted that as an answer, but if you like you can add yours as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Done, with a little extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the **Copy Bundle Resources** for your target to make sure the file has been added properly.

Usually, when when adding a new file, you can choose the targets when creating the file. Also, for each file you can add/remove the file from targets via the Utilities Pane.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I had to add "DefaultConfig.plist" to "Build Phases", "Copy Bundle Resources".